# Linq to Sql Query - better solution (optimizing)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dictionary, query-optimization

The following code works, but it's not a nice code. (low performance)

I have a dictionary with value and key.

First i go trough every webcodes who exist. Then i load all participants in a list (where webcode equals the actual webcode in the foreach). After that i add the data (parameter of the webcode and a count of participants to the dictionary).

```
        Guid compID = Guid.Parse(wID);
        ChartModel webcodes = new ChartModel();
        webcodes.Title = "Webcodes Statistics";
        webcodes.Data = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        var webcodesData = db.t_Webcode;

        foreach (var w in webcodesData)
        {
            var wData = db.t_Participant.Where(t => t.FK_Competition == compID && t.Webcode == w.Webcode);

            if (wData.Count() != 0)
                webcodes.Data.Add(w.Parameter, wData.Count());
        }

        ViewBag.Webcodes = webcodes;
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need something along these lines:

```
webcodes.Data = (from w in db.t_Webcode 
        join p in db.t_Participant on w.Webcode equals p.Webcode 
        where p.FK_Competition == compID 
        group w by w.Parameter into g 
        select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToDictionary();
```

I can't test it but that is the type of query you need.

Answer (score 0):

This will assume that you have relationships defined in your database and that your LINQ to SQL datacontext are aware of them. If not, you will need to join manually on t_Participants from tWebcode.

This should execute in 1 single SQL query, instead of 1 query per row in tWebcode.

```
var webcodesAndNoOfParticipants = 
    from webcode in db.tWebcode

    // Define number of participants for this webcode
    let numberOfParticipants = webcode.t_Participants.Count(participant => participant.FK_Competition == compID)

    where numberOfParticipants > 0
    select new {
        WebcodeParameter = webcode.Parameter,
        NoOfParticipants = numberOfParticipants 
    };

webcodes.Data = webcodesAndNoOfParticipants.ToDictionary(x => x.WebcodeParameter, x => x.NoOfParticipants);
```